# Slim PUT request empty body

Tags: php, json, put, slim

I am using slim php framework for developing REST API. I am successful in implementing POST and GET requests. I am using ContentTypes middleware as well to parse the JSON body in POST and PUT requests however my PUT request always gives empty string on the server. POST just works fine and I can get the parsed JSON as PHP associative array but cant get it in PUT request. I am using application/json in headers and I dont want to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded method.

```
    $app->map('/example/:id', function ($id) use($app, $log) {
      //$body = $app->request()->getBody();
      //using the above in other POST calls & it works but does not in this case
      $body = json_decode($app->request()->getBody()); //tried this. no success
     var_dump($body);
  } )->via ( 'PUT', 'PATCH' );
```

I am calling it via CURL like this

```
$headers = array(

    'Content-Type'=>'application/json;charset=utf-8',
);
$id = 123;
$body = array("name"=>"myfirstname","email"=>"myemail");
$json_str = json_encode($body);

$response = Requests::put($base_url.'/api/v1/example/'.$id,$headers,$json_str);
```

When I try to return the same JSON from the API it returns empty array. I tried POSTMAN on chrome and above code but does not work. What is the issue.

Update: I have verified the same code works on localhost but does not work on remote dev server. What can be the reason? Do I need to alter any settings on server?

Answer (score 0):

Slim reads [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php) to get the contents of the request body, so whatever the problem is it has to do with the particulars of that stream.

Do you have some other code that tries to read `php://input`? If so, note that this is only possible starting from PHP 5.6 (which your local machine may have when your server does not).

Comment: Slim is doing `php://input` but I am not reading it directly in my code. The confusion is POST is working and I am sure slim is reading `php://input` for post. My server is on php 5.3.13 and it seems to be the problem to me but again why post method works then?

Answer (score 0):

Try using getInstance().

```
$body = json_decode($app->getInstance()->request()->getBody());
```